# Perfect square given by ${r}^{2}+u\,r+v$, where r is variable and u,v are constants

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations, square-numbers

I am looking for solution for a problem of finding a perfect square given by

$$
{r}^{2}+u\,r+v
$$

where $u > 0$ and $v > 0$ are integer constants and expected $r >= 0$.

The closest I was able to get to is

$$
a^2 = r^2+u\,r+v
$$
$$
\sum_{c=1}^{a}2\,c-1 =  v+r\,u+\sum_{c=1}^{r}2\,c-1
$$
$$
(\sum_{c=r+1}^{a}2\,c-1)-r\,u-v = 0
$$

and I have no idea where to go from here, except for brute force search for an $r$ which would satisfy that ${r}^{2}+u\,r+v$ matches a perfect square test.

I am not sure whether there is a straightforward answer to this question, any suggestions welcomed!

Comment: Maybe this helps: $v < u$, $u$ is even,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$  (2a+2r+u)(2a-2r-u) = 4 v - u^2   $$
if $4v-u^2 = 0,$ there are infinitely many solutions. If $4v-u^2 \neq 0,$ it has a finite number of possible expressions as the product of two numbers, say
$$  4v-u^2 = PQ, $$
then solve
$$  (2a+2r+u) = P,  $$  and
$$  (2a-2r-u) = Q.  $$

Comment: Thank You very much for the effort and contribution. I understand the logic behind. My problem would be that if $4v-u^2$ gets huge, then getting P and Q gets complex and following the path might be difficult, especially if P and Q tend to be primes. I am seeking for a shortcut in choosing value of $r$ such that the equation in question will be a perfect square, regardless of the actual value of $a$

Answer (score 0):

Note that any perfect square trinomial is of the form $(x+y)^2=x^2+2xy+y^2$. If $u=2n$ and $v=n^2$ then $r^2+ur+v=r^2+2rn+n^2=(r+n)^2=a^2$. Thus for any $a^2$ there are $\left \lceil \frac{a}{2} \right \rceil$ unique equations of the type you are looking for, since $n=a-r$.

Comment: Worth noting, also, is that your equation has solutions iff $ur+v=2rn+n^2$ which, given $u$ and $v$, can be examined via the quadratic formula.